# Member based security

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I have the following data structure and I like to grant **write access on project1...projectN** only to users listed in members list of the specific project. For authentication I am using the Simplelogin mechanism.

## Data structure

```
|---projects
|       |---project1
|       |       |---members
|       |              |---simpleloginXXX : true
|       |              |---simpleloginXYZ : true
|       |---project2
|       |       |---members
|       |              |---simpleloginEFG : true
|       |              |---simpleloginXYZ : true
```

Could someone show me how to define this rule? Or do I have to reorganize the structure of the data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this will only allow a user to write to a project if they're a member of that project:

```
{
    "projects": {
        "$project": {
            ".read": true, /* anyone can read */
            ".write": "root.child('projects/'+$project+'/members/'+auth.uid).exists()"
        }
    }
}
```

### Update: allowing all users to see a list of all projects

As you already discovered: if you want to list all projects for all users, you'll need to put `.read` outside of `$project`:

```
{
    "projects": {
        ".read": true,
        "$project": {
            ".read": true, /* anyone can read */
            ".write": "root.child('projects/'+$project+'/members/'+auth.uid).exists()"
        }
    }
}
```

### Update: allowing only members to **read** a project

These rules will allow users to only see projects that they're a member of.

```
{
    "projects": {
        "$project": {
            ".read": "root.child('projects/'+$project+'/members/'+auth.uid).exists()",
            ".write": "root.child('projects/'+$project+'/members/'+auth.uid).exists()"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, thanks! The write is now working correct! The read access has to be outside of the `$project` section because otherwise I'll get a permission denied if I want to list (read) all projects. Is there a possibility to limit read access to only those projects where the logged in user is defined in the members section? For example user `simpleloginXYZ` should be able to see `project1` and `project2` but logged in user `simpleloginXXX` should only be able to see `project1`? See example above.

Comment: Sure, just set the same rule to `.write`. I'll add a few more examples. If this answers your questions, don't forget to click the check mark to the left of my answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: No, from the documentation of firebaseIO and with the test on my firebase the rule `".read": "root.child('projects/'+$project+'/members/'+auth.uid).exists()"` inside `$project` won't limit the read access to only the projects with the appropriate member. Or is it possible to `overwrite` rules from upper hierarchy levels?

Comment: Ah, that is correct indeed: once access is granted, it cannot be taken away at a lower level. If you want users to see all projects (even the ones that they don't have access to), you'll have to store that "list of project names" in a separate node.