# Group based permissions on Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I want to have group based access to data in firebase.  The issue I'm having is figuring out how to structure the data so that multiple groups can have access to the same data and allow users to belong to several different groups.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Firebase: set security rules depending on user roles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25641184/firebase-set-security-rules-depending-on-user-roles)

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26487204/member-based-security

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19520615/how-do-i-implement-role-based-access-control-in-firebase

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea of how you could do it:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVfqV.jpg

I would suggest the following Firebase rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "stackExample": {
      "groupData": {
        "$groupName": {
          ".read": "root.child('stackExample/Accounts/' + auth.uid + '/groups/' + $groupName).val() == 'true'"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This was just a quick mockup, hopefully it gives you an idea! :)

//S